# SSH-keys ipv4 ipv6 connection issue

Tags: ssh, dns, host-name-resolution

Update: I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73551/ssh-login-via-ipv6-successfull-while-using-ipv4-to-the-same-host-yields-permiss) which seems to be very related.  Not sure how exactly.

What am I missing?  I can only use ssh when it resolves through https hostnames?  Normal ssh it hangs kinda like encryption keys aren't working, but I am using keys that I know have worked in the past.

```
ssh -v server

OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 39: Applying options for server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
```

my config

```
Host server
User user
HostName x.x.x.x
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_key
```

I don't recall ever changing my /etc/ssh/ssh_config and my firewall is set to allow ssh.

Comment: `10.0.0.231:2222` is not a valid destination. Use either `ssh -p 2222 j@10.0.0.231` or `ssh ssh://j@10.0.0.231:2222`. What do you mean by "I can ssh when it resolves through https hostnames"?

Comment: oh yeah i thought I took that out, thats just aspecific port for that box.....I have servers with ssl certificates specific ssh-keys  and I can ssh to their hostnames

Comment: Would you update your question with the output of `ssh -v server`, please?

Comment: I meant `ssh -v <IP/hostname of your server>`, not the string "server".

Comment: I updated the question with info from the bad connection, it hangs after it reads the configuration file.  do you want output from the working connection?  how much should I post?

Comment: That won't be necessary. Have you tried deactivating the firewall? Are you sure the ssh server listens on the right IP and port? (you can check with `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep sshd`)

Comment: ive been trying to connect to brand new droplets on digital ocean. There shouldn't be a firewall or anything at all right?

Comment: something happens when i use an ipv6 address

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a particular port on the remote system with `ssh`, you should be using the `-p` option:

```
ssh -p 2222 j@10.0.0.231
```

When the target address does not look like an IP number, which it does not do if you add `:2222` to the end of it, `ssh` will try to resolve the whole string `10.0.0.231:2222` as a hostname using DNS.

If you find yourself connecting to this host on this port often, you may want to set up a configuration for it to make it easier.  Edit (or create) your `~/.ssh/config` file and add

```
Host thehost
    User j
    HostName 10.0.0.231
    Port 2222
```

and then use

```
ssh thehost
```

Comment: Sorry that part is irrelevant.  I thought I erased it. I've been able to access that in the past without issue and it isn't really the problem im tryin  to solve.

Comment: @JacobBruck The `ssh` client may say "connection timed out" when you use it with an IP address, but it would _not_ say "could not resolve hostname" since you're not giving it a hostname. Could you please re-run your test and insert the proper error message in the question?

Comment: Yep I'm  looking back at what is going on here. That solution does work, which tells me my test was flawed from the start..so I'm back to square one..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the full answer, but my encryption keys work with ipv6.

so two possibble answers.  I'm dumb and got ssh keys mixed up a billion times a long with my ip addresses, (very likely), but I still can't connect when I try an ipv4 address with encryption keys

So I did something to make ssh only allow encryption keys with ipv6?  I don't know if that is even a thing, or how or why. And why would ipv4 work without encryption?